# How to extract a few IP addresses from a YAML file

Tags: yaml

I have this file, and I'd like to select all the IP addresses under the `masters/hosts` section if their line is *not* commented. I tried this `sed 's/.*\ \([0-9\.]\+\).*/\1/g'`, but it did not work.

```yaml
metal:
  children:
    masters:
      hosts:
        dev0: {ansible_host: 172.168.1.10}
        # dev1: {ansible_host: 185.168.1.11}
        # dev2: {ansible_host: 142.168.1.12}
    workers:
      hosts: {}
        # dev3: {ansible_host: 172.168.1.13}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `sed` solution:

```
sed -n '/masters:/n;/hosts:/{:a n;/^ *#* *dev[0-9]/!d;s/^ *dev[0-9]: {ansible_host: //;tl;ba;:l s/}//p;ba}' test
```

in a multiline fashion :

```
    sed -n '
         /masters:/n
         /hosts:/{
             :a n
             /^ *#* *dev[0-9]/!d
             s/^ *dev[0-9]: {ansible_host: //
             tl
             ba
             :l 
                  s/}//p
                  ba
         }' test
```

The `sed` cmd do the following :

```
sed : /bin/sed the executable
-n : sed option to avoid auto printing
/masters:/n : If the current line is "master:" read the **n**ext line in the pattern space
/hosts:/{ : If the current line, the one read before, is "hosts:" do the following command block
:a n : Create a label called "a" and read the next line in the patter space.
/^ *#* *dev[0-9]/!d : If the current line, is **not** a dev[0-9] keyword (even commented) then delete current line and start a new cicle (exit from the loop)
s/^ *dev[0-9]: {ansible_host: // : sobstitute anything in the line except the ip address.
tl : If the preceding sobstitution succeded, then jump to the "l" label (skipping the next instruction).
ba : Is a commented line: Jump to the "a" label and read the next line.
:l : Create a new label called "l"
s/}//p : Remove the last "}" and print the pattern space (The ip address)
ba : Jump to label "a" to process the next line.
} : Close the code block opened by the match on the "host" line.
```

---

Or, in `awk`:

```
awk '
    /masters:/{
        f=1
        next
    }
    /hosts:/ && f {
        f++
        next
    }
    /^ *dev[0-9]: [{]ansible_host: / && f == 2 {
         sub(/[}]$/, "", $NF)
         print $NF
         next
    }
    !/^ *#? ?dev[0-9]*:/ && f==2{f=0}
' test
```

---

With `perl` and `YAML` module :

```
perl -MYAML -le '
    $y = YAML::LoadFile "test";
    %h = %{$y->{metal}->{children}->{masters}->{hosts}};
     print values $h{$_}->%* for (keys %h)
'
```

Use `%{$h{$_}}` instead of `$h{$_}->%*` if your `perl` version does not support it.

Answer (score 14):

The same way that dealing with JSON is better handled in shell with an adequate tool: [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/), what if there was a similar tool for YAML?

There is actualy a `jq` wrapper called... [`yq`](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq) that can be used like `jq` with YAML input. It doesn't appear to be packaged in distributions. Anyway once this python command is built and installed (along the mandatory `jq` tool which is widely available), one can now parse accordingly the YAML file, since it will naturally ignore comments.

```
yq -r '.metal.children.masters.hosts[].ansible_host' < myfile.yaml
```

which will dump IP addresses in masters as long as the syntax is valid.

Comment: FWIW there's also [another tool called yq](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/) which is intended for the same purpose but is a completely different implementation, independent of jq.